# edit member fields in CiviMember

Tags: civimember, fields

How do I make the field "member since" in Civimember optional? If I leave it blank I can't save a membership. To make things worse you can only select dates back 1997 (if someone has been a member since 1976 you're out of luck). Also if I don't know the date the person became a member.

Comment: Found the solution to the date problem. Field is still mandatory.

Comment: I don't believe you can avoid using this - it requires this as it denotes the commencement of the membership cycle and other things are built off that